# Grep all "a href" links, images path and names from HTML file

Tags: html, shell, grep

I have a html file with many lines like this:

```
<div class="cell small-6 medium-4 large-3">
   <a href="/some-link/">
    <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="Bitter-Orange"> <br> Bitter Orange
  </a>
</div>
```

I want to remove all "a href" elements, get all images url's and get all products names. Output must be like:

https://domainn.com/some-image.jpg/
Bitter Orange

I try with grep -o -E 'https?://[^"]+' and grep all links but how to delete them from file?

Comment: It is a fool's errand to parse HTML with regular expressions.  You need to use a programming language that has an HTML parser, like Python with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you want, there are several ways to do this, see if this one fully meets your needs. Sorry about my English.

If this is not what you want, let me know and I can help you using another approach.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.cell');
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  const div = divs[i];
  const img = div.querySelector('img');
  const name = div.querySelector('br').nextSibling.textContent.trim();
  console.log(`https://domainn.com/${img.getAttribute('src')} ${name}`);
  div.removeChild(div.querySelector('a'));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cell small-6 medium-4 large-3">
       <a href="/some-link/">
        <img src="some-image.jpg" alt="Bitter-Orange"> <br> Bitter Orange
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="cell small-6 medium-4 large-3">
       <a href="/another-link/">
        <img src="another-image.jpg" alt="Sweet-Apple"> <br> Sweet Apple
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-6 medium-4 large-3">
       <a href="/some-link/">
        <img src="some-image02.jpg" alt="Bitter-Orange02"> <br> Bitter Orange02
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="cell small-6 medium-4 large-3">
       <a href="/another-link/">
        <img src="another-image02.jpg" alt="Sweet-Apple02"> <br> Sweet Apple02
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cell small-6 medium-4 large-3">
       <a href="/some-link/">
        <img src="some-image03.jpg" alt="Bitter-Orange03"> <br> Bitter Orange03
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="cell small-6 medium-4 large-3">
       <a href="/another-link/">
        <img src="another-image03.jpg" alt="Sweet-Apple03"> <br> Sweet Apple03
      </a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // código para obter imagens e nomes de produtos
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Тhis worked perfectly for me!

Comment: Glad it helped. Mark the question as done. Success in your projects